# Who are forbidden sudo requests reported to?

Tags: sudo, sudoers

When I am forbidden to run **sudo** I get the following message:

> *barack.obama is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.*

But who is it reported to, and how?

Comment: The default on most systems is Chuck Norris.

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD reference](https://xkcd.com/838/)

Answer (score 7):

It is reported to the user configured in the [**mailto**](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/man/1.8.1/sudoers.man.html#mailto) directive in the [**sudoers**](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/man/1.8.1/sudoers.man.html) file. This defaults to `root`. You can control what gets mailed and how verbose it is with the [**mail_***](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/man/1.8.1/sudoers.man.html#mail_always)
directives.